Associated Prime containing non-regular element
I'm struggling with an exercise about associated primes.

Let $M$ be an $R$-module, and $a\in R$ be a non-regular element of $M$ (that is, $a$ is such that $m\mapsto am$ is not injective). Show that there is $\mathfrak p\in \mathrm{Ass}_R(M)$ such that $a\in \mathfrak p$.

What irks me is that there is no particular assumption about $M$ or $R$. In particular, both can be non-noetherian.
In the case where $R$ is noetherian, one can build a ascending chain of annihilators  $\mathrm{Ann}_R(m)\subsetneq \mathrm{Ann}_R(a_1m)\subsetneq \mathrm{Ann}(a_2a_1m)\subsetneq \cdots$, where $m\in M$ is nonzero such that $am=0$, and choosing $a_i$ in the following manner:

If $\mathrm{Ann}_R(a_{i-1}\cdots a_1m)$ is prime, then we found our associated prime
If not, there is $a_i, b_i\not\in \mathrm{Ann}_R(a_{i-1}\cdots a_1m)$ such that $a_ib_i\in\mathrm{Ann}_R(a_{i-1}\cdots a_1m)$, i.e. $b_i\in \mathrm{Ann}_R(a_i\cdots a_1m)$.

Since $R$ is noetherian, this chain finite and ends in a prime which does indeed contain $a$.
Can a similar argument be made in the general case ?
EDIT: I feel like the statement is wrong in the general case. Can somebody tell me if my counter example is right ?
Let's consider $R=C(\mathbf{R}, \mathbf{R})$ and $M=R$. The element $x\mapsto \min(0,x)$ is non-regular in $M$ (for example, take $x\mapsto \max(0,x)$). Let $f \neq 0$, and let's show that its annihilator is not prime. Since $f \neq 0$ and $f$ is continuous, there exist $a, b \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $0 \not\in f([a, b])$. We define $g:x \mapsto \max(0,x-(a+b)/2)$ and $h:x \mapsto \min(0,x-(a+b)/2)$. Both functions $g$ and $h$ are not in the annihilator of $f$ (because $g(a)f(a)$ and $h(b)f(b)$ are non-zero), but $gh=0$ hence $ghf=0$ and $gh \in \mathrm{Ann}(f)$. Therefore, $M$ has no associated prime.
